# How to check the current version of numpy in the source code?

Tags: python, numpy

I'd like to install nump 1.8 dev version. Where can I find the source and how can I check that's the correct version before installation.

I can't find the version number in the githbu repository here https://github.com/numpy/numpy

I'm trying to install the 1.8 dev version on Windows, but I don't know which source is the correct one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

During building, the version is substituted into `version.py` from `setup.py`:

https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/master/setup.py:

```
MAJOR               = 1
MINOR               = 8
MICRO               = 0

VERSION             = '%d.%d.%d' % (MAJOR, MINOR, MICRO)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
import numpy
print numpy.__version__
```

Like that maybe?

Comment: @siamii: Okay, then go to your Python install directory, to dist-packages/numpy, then open version.py. That's the way under ubuntu, if that file doesn't exist just search for numpy in your install directory.

Answer (score 1):

[setup.py](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/master/setup.py) contains:

```
MAJOR               = 1
MINOR               = 8
MICRO               = 0
ISRELEASED          = False
VERSION             = '%d.%d.%d' % (MAJOR, MINOR, MICRO)
```

So that source is for `1.8.0` (plus possible patches if that isn't updated with every commit).

If you use one of the [tags](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/tags), you can be sure you're getting exactly the right source code for a specific version.